# Gridview text color change in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

How to get the text color of a gridview, in my app i have used black, white and red color to differentiate the text, now i need to get the color of a text in onclick, Give me some idea to get the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: first you must put your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set onItemClickListener to:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    int color=tv.getCurrentTextColor();

                }
            });
```

Comment: I have used two classes to load the gridview values, in my adapter class loaded textview value, in my main class need to get the text color of a value

Comment: can you post your adapter code as well?? you can simply cast view in onItemClick to whatever view object you return in getView of the adapter. and call findViewById on that to find respective textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in `OnItemClick`

```
textView.getCurrentTextColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
       gridViewLocation=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewLocation);
```

Now set adapter:

gridViewLocation.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

```
gridViewLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {


            TextView textView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.getCurrentTextColor();



        }
    });
```